# Possible to simplify finding if an element exist in multiple lists?

Tags: python, syntax

This is my Python code, it's usable but... I'm sure there a way to simplify this long code.

```
if partialAnswer in primaryTrees or partialAnswer in secondaryTrees or partialAnswer in tertiaryTrees:
```

Anyone have a good answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
if any(partialAnswer in x for x in (primaryTrees, secondaryTrees, tertiaryTrees)):
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> listA = [1, 2, 3]
>>> listB = [4, 5, 6]
>>> listC = [7, 8, 9]
>>> n = 9
>>> any(n in x for x in (listA, listB, listC))
True
>>> n = 4
>>> any(n in x for x in (listA, listB, listC))
True
>>> n = 0
>>> any(n in x for x in (listA, listB, listC))
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

As I feel is obligatory for Python questions involving collections, here's an answer based on `itertools`:

```
 if partialAnswer in itertools.chain(primaryTrees, secondaryTrees, tertiaryTrees)
```

Beware though, that this answer becomes inefficient (compared with your original code) if the trees change to a different collection that implements `in` by doing something faster than a linear search.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
trees = (primaryTrees, secondaryTrees, tertiaryTrees)
if any(partialAnswer in tree for tree in trees):
    ...
```

In essence, `any()` is equivalent to a series of `or` operations on an iterable of booleans, while its cousin `all()` is equivalent to a series of [`and`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) operations.

Answer (score 1):

`partialAnswer` is in at least one of those lists if & only if it's in the concatenation of the lists, so:

```
if partialAnswer in primaryTrees + secondaryTrees + tertiaryTrees:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum`. It will be less efficient, but looks simpler.

```
if partialAnswer in sum(primaryTrees, secondaryTrees, tertiaryTrees, []):
```